# What is the difference between LINQ to Entities and the Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Simple question: What is the difference between LINQ to Entities and the Entity Framework? Up until now, I thought that both were different names to describe the same query, but I'm starting to get the feeling that it's not.

Comment: Similar question here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968138/entity-framework-vs-linq-to-entities-vs-linq-to-sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entity framework is an ORM.  Linq to Entities adds LINQ support for the entity framework.  So, AFAIK its a nice-to-have if you're using the entity framework.

Comment: I'd say it's a must-have instead of a nice-to-have :).

Answer (score 0):

I guess that Linq To Entities would be the particular subset of Linq that is implemented by the Entity Framework.

The Entity Framework covers all of the entity stuff such as:

- Entity Designer
- ESQL
- L2E
- Etc...